# Dozer throwing NullPointerException on getClassMap

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, dozer

The exception I am getting is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.getClassMap(MappingProcessor.java:1034)
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.map(MappingProcessor.java:162)
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.map(MappingProcessor.java:124)
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.map(MappingProcessor.java:119)
    at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.map(DozerBeanMapper.java:111)
    at com.shiladit.CategoryResource.get(CategoryResource.java:120)
```

I recently upgraded to dozerBeanMapper 5.3.2.

I have defined custom mappings through XML.  Where might I be going wrong?

EDIT: I saw line 1034 in MappingProcessor [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.dozer/dozer/5.3.2/org/dozer/MappingProcessor.java#MappingProcessor.getClassMap%28java.lang.Class%2Cjava.lang.Class%2Cjava.lang.String%29), where I assume classMappings is null, which probably means the custom XML mappings defined are not getting picked up.

Comment: Could you please share the solution for this, if it's working fine for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you instantiate the Mapper like this:

`Mapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
 DestinationObject destObject = 
    mapper.map(sourceObject, DestinationObject.class);`

you don't need the file with the mappings. If you instantiate mapper using the production way ([dozer documentation](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/usage.html) ) you need the dozerBeanMapping.xml file with the mapping.

`Mapper mapper = DozerBeanMapperSingletonWrapper.getInstance(); 
DestinationObject destObject =
    mapper.map(sourceObject, DestinationObject.class);`

Otherwise you will receive the exception that you posted. I have seen it debugging the source code of Dozer lib.

Are you instantiating Mapper using DozerBeanMapperSingletonWrapper ?

hope it helps